# I can't get Firebase to work on my React project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack-3

I am trying to get firebase to work on my React project (using Webpack v3), but I am having some issues.

I added `"firebase": "^4.10.1"` to my `package.json` and in a `firebase.js` file I added this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    authDomain: "DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DATA_URL",
    projectId: "ID",
    storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.database().ref().set({
    message: 'Connection Successful!'
});
```

On my `app.js` I imported that `firebase.js` file. 
`import './firebase/firebase';`

If I am not mistaking I am supposed to get the "Connection Successful!" message over in my database, but it's not working.

Instead I get a console [error](https://www.pastiebin.com/5a92243fc5d26). I looked around online and found a few people with similar errors saying that adding:

```
node: {
console: true,
fs: 'empty',
child_process: 'empty',
net: 'empty',
tls: 'empty',
dgram: 'empty',
dns: 'empty',
}
```

to my `webpack.config.json` would fix it. I tried it and id didn't really work.

I didn't get those errors any more, but instead I get `Uncaught TypeError: util.inherits is not a function` (full error [here](https://www.pastiebin.com/5a9225d71ff79)). I kept looking and found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) on the firebase documentation where they use `var firebase = require("firebase/app");` instead of `import`. I tried it and still didn't work.

I've tried to `yarn add util`, but to no avail.

Any idea why this is happening and /or how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Firebase in React this way:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
var config = {
    ...
};
var fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
fire.database().ref()...
```

1. `import firebase` and not `import * as firebase`, don't know what Firebase module do export, but maybe this change the things;
2. I init a variabile to which I assign the result of Firebase initialization (`var fire = firebase.initalize...`), then I use that to make calls to db, storage and whatever.

To me, it works flawlessly, don't know if it could be due to different versions or if it's just the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your `import`, but didn't work for me. I ended up getting `firebase@4.2.0` and using the `require` method to get it to work.